# Drawing a stick-man in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, graphics

A stickman is defined as a set of points, a set of lines between certain points, and other simple shapes (like a circle for a head).

It looks to me like the easiest route in AS3 is to use a Shape/Sprite's `Graphics` property to draw these lines, clearing and re-drawing each time the stickman changes. But some of the newer Flash 10 stuff seems to suggest a closer functionality to 3D graphics where you can define points and lines/triangles and then move the points rather than recreating all from scratch each render. Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you should look at inverse kinematics
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS33C39F6A-19F1-4848-A0F8-A3604A000067.html

Comment: Nice, but not quite what I want. I don't want a solution for the physics part, only the rendering part. I got as far as this and that's where I got lost, since my AS3 experience only goes as far as Flash 9: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSE06FE962-09BE-4460-B020-5CDC2E54C499.html

Comment: Isn't it what you were asking about!? If you can move all the parts of a structure by moving a single part they're attached to , there's no need for redrawing, is there?

Comment: Are you referring to my link or yours? IK is a _much_ bigger subject than just saving me a few render calls, but some of the stuff like Graphics Data Objects look to cover this kind of thing (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS749610B4-4709-4f75-BBA0-650BF52623CA.html)

Comment: was referring to my link... I'm still puzzled by your comment though :) What do you mean by "move the points rather than recreating all from scratch each render"?